# Java download file from internet without name in link?

Tags: java, file, url

How can i download file from internet, when it don't has a direct URL? Main question - Where can i take name and extension for file?

For example when URL = "defaultSite.com/topic/9772.png" we can take last part of string and create file "9772.png", where we save stream of bytes.

But from URL like:

http://www.skype.com/go/getskype

https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=win

we can't take file name, however byte stream we can save with no problem. So how can i download file like that?

upd:
MIME can't help, i think, becouse file can have specific (user created) extension, or it return to me application/octet-stream even for .exe file. Besides problem whit file name left.

upd2:
Yes, server return headers, but it may be without file name. 
There from skype example:

```
conn.getHeaderField 0 : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
conn.getHeaderField 1 : nginx
conn.getHeaderField 2 : application/octet-stream
conn.getHeaderField 3 : 30619240
conn.getHeaderField 4 : Thu, 28 Feb 2013 19:35:47 GMT
conn.getHeaderField 5 : bytes
conn.getHeaderField 6 : max-age=86400
conn.getHeaderField 7 : Thu, 04 Apr 2013 14:52:26 GMT
conn.getHeaderField 8 : keep-alive
conn.getHeaderField 9 : S
```

I need a reliable way to get name and extension.

Comment: The web doesn't have a concept of files, only URLs.

Comment: You need to learn about HTTP responses and MIME

Comment: HTTP response you get may contain the `Content-disposition` header with filename, but it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

More to the point, the server is not suggesting a file name. One of the HTTP Headers that a server can add to a download response is

```
Content-Disposition: filename=checkimage.jpg
```

or to give a Save As prompt

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=checkimage.jpg

(checkimage.jpg is arbitrary here.)
```

if the server does not provide a file name, then you need to make one up.  And, if it does not use the *attachment* form, the browser will use the MIME Type also provided in an HTTP Header to decide which application to open the returned data in.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.skype.com/go/getskype, I get redirected to http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-macosx-a and then to http://download.skype.com/macosx/Skype_6.3.59.582.dmg

So you need to follow the redirects, the java library you're using might do this automatically (but you haven't said which), but either way the last redirect will be to the exact URL.